# Environment not assigned to node during Chef Bootstrapping

Tags: chef-infra

I am bootstrapping node using below command. Everything is fine except environment is not getting assigned to node.

```
sudo knife bootstrap 10.99.99.99 -x root -i test.pem -N NODE_NAME --sudo --bootstrap-template custom_linux -E production -VV
```

When used `-VV` option, i found in log it is passing `-E` to chef-client but environment not getting assigned, Can any one faced the same issue.

```
(echo.{"run_list":[]}) 1>C:\chef\first-boot.json
chef-client -c c:/chef/client.rb -j c:/chef/first-boot.json -E production
 INFO: *** Chef 12.5.1 ***
 INFO: Chef-client pid: 2392
 2013536
 Line:60
^[[36mWB000767.rwest.local^[[0m [2016-02-23T16:00:56+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.5.1 ***
^[[36mWB000767.rwest.local^[[0m [2016-02-23T16:00:56+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2392
```

Comment: Command is fine and environment being overridden in next command. Sorry for the inconvenience,